# Adicionar e remover class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um esquema simples para ir para a classe `.ativo` e remover ela e adicionar a class `.block` depois procura o id `#banner1` e adiciona a class `.ativo` e remove a class `.block`

Só que não esta dando certo, olha ai :

```
$(".botao1").click(function() {
$('.ativo').removeClass('ativo').addClass('block').find($("#banner1")).addClass('ativo').removeClass('block');
});
```

Alguém sabe porque ?

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kybphv0z/)

Comment: O elemento com o id `banner1` está **dentro** do elemento com a classe `ativo`? Se não estiver, o `find` não vai retornar nenhum resultado.

Comment: Coloque o HTML também

Comment: @mgibsonbr, como localizar o id fora da classe ?

Comment: coloquei um exemplo no jsfiddle!!

Comment: Se você relaciona *botao1* com *banner1*, *botao2* com *banner2*... porque o uso de *find*? Remova `closest` do botão2

Comment: @PapaCharlie, mas o resultado não será o mesmo?

Comment: Seu problema não é com a troca da classe? Você está fazendo botões para mudar a imagem e a descrição, não é?

Comment: @PapaCharlie, isso! Esse botão1 é pra voltar para a primeira imagem e descrição. o 2 pra 2ª, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo mais simples do que você deseja, está no [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/82uy25yf/), basicamente ao clicar no botão, você oculta as descrições e aplica a visibilidade nos elementos correspondentes - descrição e imagem. Veja se o exemplo abaixo se aproxima do que deseja fazer.

<sub>**jQuery**</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function() {
        // id do elemento clicado
        id = $(this).attr( 'id' );

        // exibe / oculta descrições
        $('.description').addClass('none');
        $('#description'+id).removeClass('none').addClass('block');

        // exibe / oculta imagens
        $('.image').addClass('none');
        $('#img'+id).removeClass('none').addClass('block');
    });
});
```

<sub>**HTML**</sub>

```
<div id="banners">
    <img id="img1" src="..." class="image block">
    <img id="img2" src="..." class="image none">
    <img id="img3" src="..." class="image none">

    <div id="description1" class="description">[1] Bla bla bla</div>
    <div id="description2" class="description none">[2] Bla bla bla</div>
    <div id="description3" class="description none">[3] Bla bla bla</div>

    <button id="1">Banner 1</button>
    <button id="2">Banner 2</button>
    <button id="3">Banner 3</button>
</div>
```

<sub>**CSS**</sub>

```
.block{display:block}
.none{display:none}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem tantos botões como imagens e os nomes têm um padrão como no seu jsFiddle, pode fazer assim:

```
$('#botoes > div').each(function (i) {
    $(".botao" + i).click(function () {
        $('.ativo').removeClass('ativo').addClass('block');
        $("#banner" + i).addClass('ativo').removeClass('block');
    });
});
```

Desta maneira cada `.botão(numero)` irá mudar as classes de cada `#banner(mesmo numero)`.

Já agora no seu CSS pode simplificar os botões, caso eles sejam iguais. Em vez de ter um CSS para cada classe `.botao1`, `.botao2`, etc pode usar:

```
#botoes > div {
    width: 20px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplificar mais ainda e utilizar os próprios índices dos elementos, sem ter que definir IDs para identifica-los:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="banners">
    <img src="http://png-5.findicons.com/files/icons/2718/pretty_office_icon_set_part_11/128/number_1.png">
    <img src="http://png-3.findicons.com/files/icons/2718/pretty_office_icon_set_part_11/128/number_2.png">
    <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2718/pretty_office_icon_set_part_11/128/number_3.png">
    <div>[1] Bla bla bla</div>
    <div>[2] Bla bla bla</div>
    <div>[3] Bla bla bla</div>
    <hr>
    <button>Banner 1</button>
    <button>Banner 2</button>
    <button>Banner 3</button>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#banners img:not(:eq(0)), #banners div:not(:eq(0))').each(function() { $(this).hide(); });

    $("button").click(function () {
        $('#banners img, #banners div').hide();
        $('#banners img:eq(' + $(this).index('button') + '), #banners div:eq(' + $(this).index('button') + ')').show();
    });
});
```

Veja no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/68ev5jy9/)

<sub>PS.: Para poupar trabalho roubei descaradamente o código básico do Papa Charlie... heheh</sub>